# PIC24 PicKit3 can't debug

Tags: debugging, microchip

I'm trying to debugging my code on the PIC24F04KA200. But when i start debugging, i get the message: 
*The target device is not ready for debugging. Please check your configuration bit settings and program the device before proceeding. The most common causes for this failure are oscillator and/or PGC/PGD settings.*

I readed the PicKit3 User guide, but i don't find the answer. The PicKit is connected to the PGC2 and PGD2 pins. My configuration bits:

```
/* 
 * File:   config.h
 *
 */

#ifndef CONFIG_H
#define CONFIG_H

#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif  /* CONFIG_H */


#include <p24F04KA200.h>


// PIC24F04KA200 Configuration Bit Settings

// 'C' source line config statements

#include <xc.h>

// FBS

// FGS
#pragma config GWRP = OFF               // General Segment Code Flash Write Protection bit (General segment may be written)
#pragma config GCP = OFF                // General Segment Code Flash Code Protection bit (No protection)

// FOSCSEL
#pragma config FNOSC = FRCDIV           // Oscillator Select (8 MHz FRC oscillator with divide-by-N (FRCDIV))
#pragma config IESO = OFF               // Internal External Switch Over bit (Internal External Switchover mode disabled (Two-Speed Start-up disabled))

// FOSC
#pragma config POSCMOD = NONE           // Primary Oscillator Configuration bits (Primary oscillator disabled)
#pragma config OSCIOFNC = ON            // CLKO Enable Configuration bit (CLKO output disabled)
#pragma config POSCFREQ = MS            // Primary Oscillator Frequency Range Configuration bits (Primary oscillator/external clock input frequency between 100 kHz and 8 MHz)
#pragma config SOSCSEL = SOSCHP         // SOSC Power Selection Configuration bits (Secondary oscillator configured for high-power operation)
#pragma config FCKSM = CSECMD           // Clock Switching and Monitor Selection (Clock switching is enabled, Fail-Safe Clock Monitor is disabled)

// FWDT
#pragma config WDTPS = PS32768          // Watchdog Timer Postscale Select bits (1:32,768)
#pragma config FWPSA = PR128            // WDT Prescaler (WDT prescaler ratio of 1:128)
#pragma config WINDIS = OFF             // Windowed Watchdog Timer Disable bit (Standard WDT selected; windowed WDT disabled)
#pragma config FWDTEN = OFF             // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled (control is placed on the SWDTEN bit))

// FPOR
#pragma config BOREN = BOR0             // Brown-out Reset Enable bits (Brown-out Reset disabled in hardware; SBOREN bit disabled)
#pragma config PWRTEN = OFF             // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config BORV = LPBOR             // Brown-out Reset Voltage bits (Low-Power Brown-out reset occurs around 2.0V)
#pragma config MCLRE = ON               // MCLR Pin Enable bit (MCLR pin enabled; RA5 input pin disabled)

// FICD
#pragma config ICS = PGx2               // Reserved (PGC2/PGD2 are used for programming the device)

// FDS
#pragma config DSWDTPS = DSWDTPSF       // Deep Sleep Watchdog Timer Postscale Select bits (1:2,147,483,648 (25.7 Days))
#pragma config DSLPBOR = OFF            // Deep Sleep Zero-Power BOR Enable bit (Deep Sleep BOR disabled in Deep Sleep)
#pragma config DSWDTEN = OFF            // Deep Sleep Watchdog Timer Enable bit (DSWDT disabled)
```

And my main file:

```
/* 
 * File:   main.c
 */
#include "config.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    while(1)
    {
        ;
    }
}
```

The processor is running. I have a blinkerLed program running. 
Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That micro-controller does not have embedded debugging capabilities. If you want to debug your application for this UC, you'll have to use an emulator or the simulator (not my favorite but it can sometimes get you out of a bind).

From the Microchip website:

> Featuring nanoWatt XLP Technology ideal for battery applications
>   (Please use PIC24F16KA102 Processor Extention Pack for Emulation and
>   Debug Support-AC244028. **This MCU does not have on-chip debug
>   capability)**